# cannot get relatedTo by slug only ID

Tags: categories, category, relatedto

Can someone tell me why I am going crazy and cannot figure this simple relatedTo issue out?

So I have a categories section called Case Studies and several categories within. I am trying to filter the results to show all entries within a specific category.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('caseStudies').relatedTo('municipal').find() %}
```

won't show any results but using the ID will.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('caseStudies').relatedTo(422).find() %}
```

I've tried all sorts of slugs and nothing is showing. Why can I not figure this out. someone please point out my obvious mistake...

My entry field is called 'caseStudyCategory'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because the function does not accept slugs. Not sure what to answer here. It only accepts objects of type `Element` and ids as identifier.

You can see the magic here

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
if (is_numeric($element)) {
    $relElementIds[] = $element;
} else if ($element instanceof ElementInterface) {
    $relElementIds[] = $element->id;
} else if ($element instanceof ElementQueryInterface) {
    foreach ($element->ids() as $id) {
        $relElementIds[] = $id;
    }
}
```

These are all kind of things that the `relatedTo` can use/work with. If you want to get a relation by slug you have to fetch the element first.

```
.relatedTo(craft.categories.slug('municipal').one())
```

Comment: @terryupton Assuming you're in a category template, you could also just do `.relatedTo(category)` as well.